# Average number of required swaps in selection sort

Tags: sorting

Assume that the distinct integers 1,...,*N* are in random order and need to be
sorted using selection sort.  Here I am interested in the average number of
swaps required, rather than the number of comparisons.  Self-swaps are not
counted.  Running the selection sort over every possible permutation for a
given *N* provides the following average number of swaps:

```
        N        Total swaps     Average number of swaps

        2        1               0.5
        3        7               1.1667
        4        46              1.9167
        5        326             2.7167
        6        2556            3.5500
        7        22,212          4.4071
        8        212,976         5.2821
        9        2,239,344       6.1710
```

Is there a formula for the total or average number of required swaps?  A linear
least-squares fit produces
$$
 0.816411N - 1.27647
$$
for the average, but it is inexact.  The code presented at
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#Implementations was used.

Comment: It looks like your numbers are wrong. For instance, for $N=3$ there should be $6\cdot\left(\frac23+\frac12\right)=7$ swaps.

Comment: Yep, a silly programming mistake, thanks.  The table and linear approximation
have been corrected above.

Answer (score 2):

Among $N!$ permutations, $(N-1)!$ of them have the minimal element in the correct position, and do not require a swap; $N1 - (N-1)!$ do require it. That is, the average number of swaps to place the first element is $1 - \dfrac{1}{N}$, and then you are left with a random set of $N-1$ elements. That is, an average number of swaps is $S_N = 1 - \dfrac{1}{N} + A_{N-1}$. Expanding, obtain $S_N = N - H_N \approx N - \ln N - \gamma$